# Error cv2::cornerEigenValsVecs during corner Harris detection

Tags: python, opencv

i am trying to use cornerHarris to detect the corners, however i am getting error
'''

```
OpenCV(3.4.1) C:\Miniconda3\conda-bld\opencv-suite_1533128839831\work\modules\imgproc\src\corner.cpp:269: error: (-215) src.type() == (((0) & ((1 << 3) - 1)) + (((1)-1) << 3)) || src.type() == (((5) & ((1 << 3) - 1)) + (((1)-1) << 3)) in function cv::cornerEigenValsVecs
```

'''
the code written is
'''

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img = cv2.imread("watch.jpg")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = np.float64(gray)
dis = cv2.cornerHarris(gray,2,3,0.001)
dis = cv2.dilate(dis)
img[dis>0.001*dis.max()] = [0,255,255]
cv2.imshow("result",img)
if cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xff==27:
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

'''
Any help would be helpful.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: try `gray = np.float32(gray)`

Comment: didnt work :( for me